# CW structure on the quotient of group action

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

If X is CW complex and G is finite group acting on X via cellular homeomorphism i.e. each element g preserves k - skeleton. I am trying to show that X/G has CW structure. I am doing by taking examples but not getting any particular idea to approach. Can someone help me?

Comment: You are trying to prove a false statement. One reason it fails is the existence of wild involutions on $R^3$. https://lamington.wordpress.com/2017/04/08/bings-wild-involution/

Comment: Oh really. Can you explain me ?

Comment: Read first about wild involutions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a specific example. Consider $S^3$ with the standard cellular structure (single 0-cell $\{x\}$ and single 3-cell). Let $\sigma: S^3\to S^3$ be a wild involution fixing $x$. Then $\sigma$ is cellular. However, the quotient $S^3/\langle \sigma\rangle$ is not homeomorphic to a CW complex.